# toggle buttons sending different strings

Tags: java, android, xml

I have two toggle buttons that are suppose to send out different string code every time i press them. But the problem is that the buttons are sending the same string code '101' and I couldn't figure out how to get them to send different code '101' & '102'. Any advice?

java code

```
    public void onToggleClicked(View view) {    
        // Is the toggle on?    
        boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked(); 


        if (on) {        
            String str = "101".toString();  
            sendToServer(str);    
            } else {        
                String str = "000".toString();  
                sendToServer(str); 
                }
    }
        public void onToggleClicked1(View view) {    
            // Is the toggle on?    
            boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked(); 

            if (on) {  

                String str = "201".toString();  
                sendToServer(str);    
                } else {        
                    String str = "000".toString();  
                    sendToServer(str);    
                    }
```

xml code

```
<ToggleButton
         android:id="@+id/togglebutton"
         android:layout_width="350dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_x="30dp"
         android:layout_y="135dp"
         android:onClick="onToggleClicked"
         android:textOff="Light1- OFF"
         android:textOn="Light1- ON"
         android:textSize="40dip" />


<ToggleButton
         android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
         android:layout_width="350dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_x="30dp"
         android:layout_y="440dp"
         android:onClick="onToggleClicked"
         android:text="ToggleButton"
         android:textOff="Light2- OFF"
         android:textOn="Light2- ON"
         android:checked="false" 
         android:textSize="40dip" />
```

Comment: please send the full code:0 i think you are calling the first one each time, that is why the second is not reeving  the click event.

Comment: This code could be written much better than this. You should consider simplifying the code.

Comment: as i said that you are calling same function on event ... please follow the approach hi if you will look like the code

 android:onClick="onToggleClicked"
in layouts every time you are calling the same

so make another as

 android:onClick="onToggleClicked1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your toggle buttons are calling the same function. Change one in the xml to read:

```
android:onClick="onToggleClicked1"
```

Comment: you can use  a switch case with `view.getId()`

Answer (score 0):

wishing you a new year-2014...please follow the approach
hi if you will look like the code

```
 android:onClick="onToggleClicked"
```

in layouts every time you are calling the same

so make another as

```
 android:onClick="onToggleClicked1"
```

for a better approach and understanding write the code like this for first button

```
   ToggleButton b = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);

    // attach an OnClickListener
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // your click actions go here

        }
    });
```

write the code like this for second button

```
    ToggleButton b1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

    // attach an OnClickListener
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // your click actions go here

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
  ToggleButton button1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
  ToggleButton button2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

  button1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
              if (isChecked) {         
                  String str = "101";  
                  sendToServer(str);    
              } else {
                  String str = "000";  
                  sendToServer(str); 
              }
      }
  });

  button2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
              if (isChecked) {         
                  String str = "201";  
                  sendToServer(str);    
              } else {
                  String str = "000";  
                  sendToServer(str); 
              }
      }
  });
```

Or

```
       public void onToggleClicked(View view) {    
              // Is the toggle on?    
              boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked(); 

              if(R.id.togglebutton == view.getId()){
                   if (on) { 
                        String str = "101".toString();  
                        sendToServer(str);    
                   } else {        
                        String str = "000".toString();  
                        sendToServer(str);   
                   } 
              }
              if(R.id.togglebutton1 == view.getId()){
                   if (on) { 
                        String str = "201".toString();  
                        sendToServer(str);    
                   } else {        
                        String str = "000".toString();  
                        sendToServer(str);   
                   } 
              }
        }
```